# How to upload multiple files into different documents in XPages?

Tags: file-upload, xpages

I have a need to upload up to 5 files at the same time using 5 different file upload controls and all files need to be stored into seperate notes documents. there should be only one save button

So if I upload 5 files and save there should be 5 Notes documents containg 1 file each

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I've not cleaned this up enough from MWLug - my my solution is fileVault which you can grab here.  https://bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault
There are slides inside the repository but I don't have true documentation yet.  The next step will be a NotesIn9 Video that's coming very soon.

What this is, is a combination of PLupload and Java so allow the uploading of multiple files that get saved 1 per document in a series of Vault databases.  There are 3 databases for JPG's..  (Original, Large, and Small) and 1 .nsf for other files.

I don't use the built in file upload or download control at all. So if you really want that you can ignore this.

I have some custom controls in there for displaying pictures and files as well as a lightbox custom control - Galleria.

We use this in production currently but this version of it could use some more cleaning up and documentation.  but you're welcome to try it.

The repository has the raw source which is best to use but it also has compiled templates if that's easier.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Create an xpage with 5 panels, bind each to different document data source with ignoreRequestPatams=false.

Have a file upload and download control inside each panel.
Select full update for the file upload on change event.

Create save button on top of all 5 panels to save all 5 data sources.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that seem to work.
I put a document datasource and a file upload control in a repeat and then use a link to save all data sources. I set the repeat to 5 and this will create 5 documents.

In postSaveDocument on the data source I delete the onces that did not contain an attachment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:panel>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:5}">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="d" formName="Main">
                    <xp:this.postSaveDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(@AttachmentLengths()==0){
d.getDocument().remove(true)
}}]]></xp:this.postSaveDocument>
                </xp:dominoDocument>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{d.Body}"></xp:fileUpload>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
<xp:link escape="true" text="Save" id="link1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:save(true)}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```